# Настройка Apache2 + Kerberos в Докере - ошибка No key table entry found for

Tags: docker, debian, docker-compose, apache2, kerberos

Настраиваю Apache2 + Kerberos в Докере.
файл.keytab - есть. Настройки в krb5.conf - верные.

```
root@container:/# klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/ticket
Default principal: учётка@DOMEN.RU

Valid starting     Expires            Service principal
03/15/24 04:42:42  03/15/24 14:42:42  krbtgt/DOMEN.RU@DOMEN.RU
        renew until 03/22/24 04:42:32
```

Настройки в Апач:

```
    <Location "/">
       AuthType Kerberos
       AuthName "УЧЁТКА"
       KrbMethodNegotiate on
       KrbMethodK5Passwd off
       KrbServiceName HTTP/имя_сервера.DOMEN.ru@DOMEN.RU
       KrbAuthRealms DOMEN.RU
       Krb5Keytab /etc/apache2/имя_сервера.keytab
       KrbLocalUserMapping On
       Require valid-user
    </Location>
```

ОШИБКА:

```
[Fri Mar 15 04:39:57.061033 2024] [auth_kerb:error] [pid 10:tid 140193378916096] [client 10.108.77.177:58138] gss_accept_sec_context() failed: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information (, No key table entry found for HTTP/имя_сервера.DOMEN.ru@DOMEN.RU)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При использовании модуля для Apache libapache2-mod-auth-kerb или mod-auth-kerb ошибка была не очень информативная, тем более и сам модуль устарел и не рекомендован к использованию.
При использовании модуля libapache2-mod-auth-gssapi ошибка появилась другая:

```
[Tue Mar 19 09:59:06.511296 2024] [auth_gssapi:error] [pid 10:tid 140228761200320] [client 10.108.77.177:59587] GSS ERROR In Negotiate Auth: gss_accept_sec_context() failed: [Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information (Request ticket server HTTP/name_of_.domen.ru@DOMEN.RU kvno 5 found in keytab but not with enctype rc4-hmac)]
```

Решить проблему с не авторизацией и этой ошибкой помогло:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**в свойствах учётной записи установить "Данная учётная запись поддерживает 128\256 битное шифрование"**